# Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist'

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the below error after i ran this command `composer dump-autoload`. However, before running this command, it was working fine.

```
Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class 
App\Console\Kernel does not exist' in 
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:719
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the path: `/your_root/app/Console`

See if you have **Kernel.php** file there. This file registers all commands.

Maybe somehow you have deleted the file and thats why you are getting the error.

Comment: Accurate path would be "resource\App\Console\Kernel ". But its not going inside resource.

Comment: In my all Laravel Projects correct path was and is: `my_root\app\Console\Kernel.php` ,

Answer (score 0):

I had the file in my app\Console folder, but I got this message after all artisan and composer commands. I solved it by creating a new kernel.php file, copying all the content from the original file.